# Convert input file to image with react js and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am facing a problem that i can't find a solution since a week . I am working with node Js and i have to convert a PDF to Image so i use pdf-poppler  and here is the code . The problem is that i am storing my PDF file into MongoDB and the file here need the path of the PDF file i don't know how to put the path of my file which is stored into MongoDB :

```
const path = require('path');
const pdf = require('pdf-poppler');

let file = 'C:\\tmp\\convertme.pdf'

let opts = {
    format: 'jpeg',
    out_dir: path.dirname(file),
    out_prefix: path.baseName(file, path.extname(file)),
    page: null
}

pdf.convert(file, opts)
    .then(res => {
        console.log('Successfully converted');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for people finding the same issue just try to use the package node js pdf-poppler and it will work as magic